# Mind twisting implied this.var access

Tags: javascript

```
x = {}

function f1 () {
    this.v1 = 'cool'
    try { console.log('v1:', v1) } catch(e){ console.log('error') }
}

f1.bind(x)()
f1()
f1.bind(x)()
f1()
```

#### Output:

```
error
v1: cool
v1: cool
v1: cool
```

Please explain why this code prints `error` once, and then `cool`.

Why would `v1` without `this` work at all in the first place?

Comment: because in the second call to f1, `this` equals the `window` or global object and so now `v1` is a global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're logging not `this.v1`, but simply `v1`. This is a reference to a global `v1` variable that is supposed to be defined on `window`. Every time you log not `x.v1`, but `window.v1`.

`this` in a function without bounded scope refers to global `window`. So when you call it first time, `v1` is created on `x`, but when you call it the second time, it is created on `window`.

Answer (score 1):

The second call to `f1()` without `bind()` - where `this` is implicitly `window`, assigns the global variable `v1` (or `window.v1`) to `'cool'` and that is the value that is printed thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

Why can you use the v1 without this keyword ?

Because your "this" keyword will be bound to "window" object, which is special.
In case of window, the variable object is the same as its "this" object/context.

Simply put, variables and properties on window object are one and the same.

Below is an example from ECMA-262.

```
var a = new String('test');

alert(a); // directly, is found in VO(globalContext): "test"

alert(window['a']); // indirectly via global === VO(globalContext): "test"
alert(a === this.a); // true

var aKey = 'a';
alert(window[aKey]); // indirectly, with dynamic property name: "test"
```